# Check if List contains an instance equal to a given one

Tags: c#, instance

I don't want to loop through the list comparing each property. Something with this functionality:

```
class myClass
{
    public int I { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<myClass> l = new List<myClass>();

        myClass x = new myClass();
        x.I = 1;
        l.Add(x);

        myClass y = new myClass();
        y.I = 2;
        l.Add(y);

        myClass z = new myClass();
        z.I = 2;

        if (l.ContainsAnInstanceEqualTo(z))
            Console.WriteLine("Contains");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: I have no control over the class and there are a few properties which should have the same value.

Comment: [Override Equals and GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). [List.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) will use your overriden implementation then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my try at creating an EqualityComparer that should compare public instance properties of any class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public int I { get; set; }
        public string S { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<MyClass> hs = new HashSet<MyClass>(new SamePublicPropertiesInstance());

            MyClass x = new MyClass();
            x.I = 1;
            x.S = "1";
            hs.Add(x);
            MyClass y = new MyClass();
            y.I = 2;
            y.S = "1";
            hs.Add(y);
            MyClass z = new MyClass();
            z.I = 2;
            z.S = "1";
            hs.Add(z);

            foreach (MyClass m in hs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I: {0} S: {1}", m.I, m.S);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

class SamePublicPropertiesInstance : EqualityComparer<object>
{
    public override bool Equals(object o1, object o2)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] pInfos = o1.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        string pName;
        bool equal;
        MethodInfo methodInfo;

        foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in pInfos)
        {
            pName = pInfo.Name.ToString();
            methodInfo = o1.GetType().GetProperty(pName).GetGetMethod();
            equal = methodInfo.Invoke(o1, null).ToString() 
                    == 
                    methodInfo.Invoke(o2, null).ToString();
            if (!equal) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(object o)
    {
        return 1.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should make `myClass` implement `IEquatable<myClass>` (or *at least* override `Equals(object)`) and then just use:

```
if (l.Contains(z))
```

(You should also rename the class to follow .NET naming conventions...)

If you don't provide an `Equals` method, you've got to specify what sort of equality you're interested in *somehow*. You can do this via something like `Find` with a predicate:

```
var found = l.Find(c => c.I == z.I);
if (found != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Or using LINQ:

```
var any = l.Any(c => c.I == z.I);
```

but it would be better to override `Equals` if there *is* a natural sense of equality.

(`List<T>.Contains` won't use your implementation of `GetHashCode`, but you should implement it in line with your `Equals` method anyway...)

Comment: Forgot to say I have no control over the class

Comment: Then use the LINQ-approach mentioned by Jon.

Comment: There are a few properties. How to compare then all?

Comment: @Clodoaldo: Are you searching for something like that? `var any = l.Any(c => c.I == z.I && c.II = z.II && c.III = z.III);`

Comment: @Otiel That works but I was searching for something less verbose as there are quite a few properties.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: You could implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` instead. You'd still need to have all the property comparisons, but if you put them in a method instead, it may be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Contains` method with a `Predicate<myClass>`:

```
if (l.Contains(item => item.I == z.I))
    Console.WriteLine("Contains");
```

Comment: How to compare more than one property?

Comment: You could write a more complicated lambda expression such as `item => item.I == z.I && item.J == z.J`, but much more than that I would write a method that receives two instances of the class and compares them, returning a `bool`: `l.Contains(item => IsTheSame(item, z))`

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing some of the terminology here... In your example, even if Y and Z have the same values for I, **they're not the same instance.** If you are hoping to figure out whether or not their values are the same, you could either override the [`Object.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method, or you could use [`Object.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) method. You could even consider possibly using a Dictionary in some fashion.

If you are trying to determine whether or not the *exact instance* of the element that you're trying to add already exists in the list, you may want to consider looking at a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class ObjectExtension
{
    #region Public Methods

    public static bool ExEquals<T>(this T obj, T objToCompare)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            return StringExtension.ExEquals(obj as string, objToCompare as string);
        return obj.Equals(objToCompare);
    }

    public static bool ExHasAllEquals<T>(this T obj, params T[] objArgs)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < objArgs.Length; index++)
            if (ExEquals<T>(obj, objArgs[index]) == false) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static bool ExHasEquals<T>(this T obj, params T[] objArgs)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < objArgs.Length; index++)
            if (ExEquals<T>(obj, objArgs[index])) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool ExHasNoEquals<T>(this T obj, params T[] objArgs)
    {
        return ExHasEquals<T>(obj, objArgs) == false;
    }

    public static bool ExHasNotAllEquals<T>(this T obj, params T[] objArgs)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < objArgs.Length; index++)
            if (ExEquals<T>(obj, objArgs[index])) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static bool ExIsNone(this object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return true;

        if (obj.Equals(DBNull.Value)) return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static bool ExNotEquals<T>(this T obj, T objToCompare)
    {
        return ExEquals<T>(obj, objToCompare) == false;
    }

    #endregion Public Methods
}


public static class StringExtension
{
    #region Public Methods

    public static bool ExContains(this string fullText, string value)
    {
        return ExIndexOf(fullText, value) > -1;
    }

    public static bool ExEquals(this string text, string textToCompare)
    {
        return text.Equals(textToCompare, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static bool ExHasAllEquals(this string text, params string[] textArgs)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < textArgs.Length; index++)
            if (ExEquals(text, textArgs[index]) == false) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static bool ExHasEquals(this string text, params string[] textArgs)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < textArgs.Length; index++)
            if (ExEquals(text, textArgs[index])) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool ExHasNoEquals(this string text, params string[] textArgs)
    {
        return ExHasEquals(text, textArgs) == false;
    }

    public static bool ExHasNotAllEquals(this string text, params string[] textArgs)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < textArgs.Length; index++)
            if (ExEquals(text, textArgs[index])) return false;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified string
    /// in the current System.String object using StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.
    /// A parameter specifies the type of search to use for the specified string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fullText">
    /// The string to search inside.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="value">
    /// The string to seek.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The index position of the value parameter if that string is found, or -1 if it
    /// is not. If value is System.String.Empty, the return value is 0.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
    /// fullText or value is null.
    /// </exception>
    public static int ExIndexOf(this string fullText, string value)
    {
        return fullText.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static bool ExNotEquals(this string text, string textToCompare)
    {
        return ExEquals(text, textToCompare) == false;
    }

    #endregion Public Methods
}
```